# Even number should be return Uppercase

Tags: javascript, node.js

Create a function on String that takes an integer `n` as parameter.
If `n` is an **even** number, it should return the string in **uppercase**.
If `n` is **odd**, it should return the string in **lowercase**.

Basically, I need to write a script to make the following possible.

`'stringname'.functionName(5)` should return `'stringname'`
`'stringname'.functionName(4)` should return `'STRINGNAME'`

```
var i=2;
module.exports = function(i) {
     return String(stringname)["to"+(i%2?"Low":"Upp")+"erCase"]();    
}
```

but unfortunately I'm not able to achieve my desired output.

Comment: How is this nodejs?

Answer (score 4):

```js
String.prototype.upperIfEven = function(n){
   return (n % 2 == 0) ? this.toUpperCase() : this.toLowerCase();
}

var odd = "Hello".upperIfEven(5)

var even = "Hello".upperIfEven(6)

console.log("Odd -> ",odd)

console.log("Even -> ",even)
```

Comment: it is not showing out put.. it showing only white screen in the output

Comment: @RobG Yeah, but not recommended . It's very unclear for the first time.

Comment: You might want to add some logic which anticipates that an unwary user might call `convertor` with a string (non-numeric) input.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function upperIfEven(input, n) {
    return (n % 2 == 0) ? input.toUpperCase() : input.toLowerCase();
}

console.log(upperIfEven('Hello World', 10));
console.log(upperIfEven('Hello World', 3));
```

Comment: could you please write complete program.. I'm new to node js

Comment: Adding demo now...30 seconds

Comment: I gave a generic JavaScript answer.  Can you not integrate my answer into your own needs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with the method names for changing the cases according to even/odd values.

```js
function upperIfEven(input, n) {
    return input[['toUpperCase', 'toLowerCase'][n % 2]]();
}

console.log(upperIfEven('Hello World', 10));
console.log(upperIfEven('Hello World', 3));
```